# How can I make a jQuery post in CakePHP to edit username/password?

Tags: jquery, cakephp

**TL;DR:** I am having some trouble setting up a `POST` with jQuery and having trouble setting up my action (aka post handler). Could someone give me an example of how I setup the action/view and how I would post from jQuery

---

So, I have done some digging around, but I still cannot get it to work and haven't found what I am unsure of. So, I think I got the post part down, but I am not really sure how to setup my post request handler. More specifically, I am not sure how do I setup the controller's action and view so that I can get a proper response back with a message (success/error/validator errors). For username, I am using an e-mail and from what I have read in the documentation, as long as you set your `id` then it will update the record. However, I am getting so weird problems, as it is updating my password too, even though it is not being sent as a part of the jQuery post. Another thing is that, I noticed even though I was able to successfully able to update the email, the current page that I am on is not updating the email. I am assuming I have to re-set the value after checking for a success. Can anyone be so kind to show me an example?

Here's what I have:

Action:

```
public function edit() {
    $this->autoRender = false; // I am not sure if I need this
    Configure::write('debug', 0 ); // I think this disables all the extra debug messages I get with jQuery
    $this->disableCache(); // No idea why I need this

    if($this->request->is('ajax')) {

        $id = $this->Auth->user('id');
        // Going to be adding other cases for name/password/etc...
        switch($this->params->data['post']) {
            case 'email':
                $result = $this->updateEmail($this, $id,  $this->params->data);
                break;

        }

    }

}

private function updateEmail($object, $id=null, $request=null) {
            // Do I need to re-log them back in after I change their email to create a new session?
    $object->AccountDetail->User->id = $id;
    if($object->AccountDetail->User->save($request)) {
        return $this->Session->setFlash(__('Your email has been updated!'));
    } else {
        return  $this->Session->setFlash(__($object->AccountDetail->User->validationErrors));
    }
}
```

jQuery Post:

```
 $('#email :button').click( function () {
        $.post('/account/edit', {post: 'email', email: $('#email').val() });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. This will update only field, not entire row;

```
saveField(<fieldname>, <data>, <validation>);   // structure of saveField() method

$object->AccountDetail->User->saveField('email', $request, false);

if($object->AccountDetail->User->saveField('email', $request, false)) {
    return $this->Session->setFlash(__('Your email has been updated!'));
} else {
    return  $this->Session->setFlash(__($object->AccountDetail->User->validationErrors));
}
```

you can update your `updateEmail()` function to `updateField()` like following:

```
private function updateField($object, $field = null, $id=null, $request=null) {
            // Do I need to re-log them back in after I change their email to create a new session?
    $object->AccountDetail->User->id = $id;
    if($object->AccountDetail->User->saveField($field, $request, false)) {
        return $this->Session->setFlash(__("Your $field has been updated!"));
    } else {
        return  $this->Session->setFlash(__($object->AccountDetail->User->validationErrors));
    }
}
```

And use it like:

```
$result = $this->updateField($this, 'email', $id,  $this->params->data);
```